# Mobile App is not showing data from api using emulator

Tags: angularjs, debugging, ionic-framework, mobile

I have created a simple mobile app using Ionic version 1 and angularJS and I am trying to run my app in emulator but it is not displaying data from API while it is displaying data in a browser

I have a created mobile app using ionic version 1 and angularJS and I want to get records from API. And I have included API at my code but I want to see  data at my mobile for this purpose I am trying to run my app in the emulator using this command

```
"ionic cordova emulate android"
```

But it is not displaying data and while it is displaying data in a browser from API.

How can I display data in mobile  and how can I debug of my mobile app

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: There is no any error in the console

Comment: did you use a virtual host as your api url?

Comment: I did not use virtual host

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are hitting the api or it shows 404 error. If its not able to connects and show 404 error then you have to use ionic whitelist plugin and then have to add allow navigaton in config.xml pointing to your www.domian.com. Hope this helps